# Run CircleCI 2.0 build using several JDKs

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

I would like to run my Circle CI 2.0 build using Open JDK 8 & 9. Are there any YAML examples available explaining how to build a Java project using multiple JDK versions?

Currently I trying to add an new job `java-8` to my build. But I do not want to repeat all the step of my default Java 9 `build` job. Is there a DRY approach for this?

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/openjdk:9-jdk

    working_directory: ~/repo

    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx1g
      TERM: dumb

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Run all tests
      - run: gradle check

  java-8:
    - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk
```

Comment: Can you please post your final solution? Does the accepted answer works as written?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [YAML anchors](http://blog.daemonl.com/2016/02/yaml.html) to achieve a reasonable DRY approach. For instance, it might look like:

```
  version: 2
  shared: &shared
    working_directory: ~/repo
    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx1g
      TERM: dumb
    steps:
      - checkout
      # Run all tests
      - run: gradle check

  jobs:
    java-9:
      docker:
        - image: circleci/openjdk:9-jdk
      <<: *shared

    java-8:
      docker:
        - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk
      <<: *shared
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sharing my own solution for this problem.

The basic routing is using `workflows`

```
version: 2
jobs:
  jdk8:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk-stretch
    steps:
      - ...
  jdk11:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:11-jdk-stretch
    steps:
      - ...
workflows:
  version: 2
  work:
    jobs:
      - jdk8
      - jdk11
```

Now we can use the way explained on the [accepted anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48996813/330457).

```
version: 2
shared: &shared
  steps:
    - checkout
    - restore_cache:
        key: proguard-with-maven-example-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
    - run: mvn dependency:go-offline
    - save_cache:
        paths:
          - ~/.m2
        key: proguard-with-maven-example-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
    - run: mvn package
jobs:
  jdk8:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk-stretch
    <<: *shared
  jdk11:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:11-jdk-stretch
    <<: *shared
workflows:
  version: 2
  work:
    jobs:
      - jdk8
      - jdk11
```